# Spring Rest cannot find JPARepository while deployed

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm pretty new to Java, and for a University project i have to setup a Restful Service. So i had managed to do so a very simple hello world service with Intellij Idea IDE. Later on i wanted to add a database and setup some deployment options. So i setup my own Tomcat Server, and on each build i was deploying my .war to the Tomcat.

So i added my database, implemented Repository, Controller and Model, and when i'm debugging everything works just fine. Whatsoever when it gets deployed on my tomcat i get the following errors.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2016-11-20 11:23:47.227  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] g.d.t.backend.ServletInitializer         : Starting ServletInitializer on Atlantis with PID 15920 (started by Nikolas in K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\bin)
2016-11-20 11:23:47.228  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] g.d.t.backend.ServletInitializer         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-11-20 11:23:47.295  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@26f0ef9e: startup date [Sun Nov 20 11:23:47 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-20 11:23:48.531  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1235 ms
2016-11-20 11:23:49.240  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-11-20 11:23:49.241  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-20 11:23:49.244  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-20 11:23:49.244  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-20 11:23:49.244  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-20 11:23:49.245  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-20 11:23:49.284  WARN 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Failed to introspect bean class [gr.devian.talosquests.backend.UserController] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository
2016-11-20 11:23:49.292  INFO 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2016-11-20 11:23:49.298 ERROR 15920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Failed to introspect bean class [gr.devian.talosquests.backend.UserController] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:269) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1073) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2268) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:811) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        ... 45 common frames omitted

20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.300 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Failed to introspect bean class [gr.devian.talosquests.backend.UserController] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:269)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1073)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2268)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:811)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:247)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        ... 45 more

20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.302 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\ROOT.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.303 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\ROOT.war has finished in 4,956 ms
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.305 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\docs
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.369 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\docs has finished in 64 ms
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.370 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\examples
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.608 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\examples has finished in 238 ms
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.609 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\host-manager
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.630 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\host-manager has finished in 21 ms
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.630 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\manager
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.655 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory K:\Site\Apache Tomcat 8.5.8\webapps\manager has finished in 25 ms
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.660 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-9090]
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.669 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
20-Nov-2016 11:23:49.670 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 5360 ms
```

While Debugging on my IDE it runs just correctly. Does anyone have any idea why i'm facing this issue?

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

***Edit:***
On my IDE it also runs on Tomcat

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2016-11-20 11:14:50.013  INFO 20380 --- [           main] g.d.t.b.TalosQuestsBackendApplication    : Starting TalosQuestsBackendApplication on Atlantis with PID 20380 (C:\Users\Nikolas\IdeaProjects\TalosQuests\TalosQuestsBackend\target\classes started by Nikolas in C:\Users\Nikolas\IdeaProjects\TalosQuests\TalosQuestsBackend)
2016-11-20 11:14:50.015  INFO 20380 --- [           main] g.d.t.b.TalosQuestsBackendApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-11-20 11:14:50.056  INFO 20380 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@13b84b8: startup date [Sun Nov 20 11:14:50 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-20 11:14:51.161  INFO 20380 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f712e35] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-11-20 11:14:51.552  INFO 20380 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-11-20 11:14:51.562  INFO 20380 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-11-20 11:14:51.562  INFO 20380 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2016-11-20 11:14:51.645  INFO 20380 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-11-20 11:14:51.645  INFO 20380 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1592 ms
2016-11-20 11:14:51.778  INFO 20380 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-11-20 11:14:51.780  INFO 20380 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-20 11:14:51.781  INFO 20380 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-20 11:14:51.781  INFO 20380 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-20 11:14:51.781  INFO 20380 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-20 11:14:51.976  INFO 20380 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-11-20 11:14:51.990  INFO 20380 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-11-20 11:14:52.055  INFO 20380 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2016-11-20 11:14:52.057  INFO 20380 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-11-20 11:14:52.060  INFO 20380 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-11-20 11:14:52.095  INFO 20380 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-11-20 11:14:52.403  INFO 20380 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-11-20 11:14:52.773  INFO 20380 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-11-20 11:14:52.930  INFO 20380 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-11-20 11:14:53.332  INFO 20380 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@13b84b8: startup date [Sun Nov 20 11:14:50 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: not related to your question, but: always specify the versions of your dependencies. Without those, maven might pull a different version on the next build, breaking your application.

Comment: In this case the versions are specified in the spring-boot parent. So it is quite correct to not specify the versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your exceptions is this one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
```

So the jar which contains this class is not on your classpath.

In order to find out why this is the case, we need more information about what you mean when you say "deployed on my tomcat". What exactly are you doing?

You can also debug it from the other side: You are probably deploying some kind of jar or war. Check what is in there. You probably find that it does not contain a spring-data-commons.jar, although it should. If this is true the question becomes:

- is only that or very few jars missing?
- or are basically all missing except the jar with your own code?

Note: you can unzip jar and war files, since they are just zip files

Comment: It seems it is the onlyone missing. In /WEB-INF/lib i can locate almost everything
http://www.devian.gr/lib.png

Comment: Hibernate is not there either.

Comment: Ok i found the issue. On the war i was deploying the new libraries were not inserted. I fixed it. thank you.